# Почему рекурсивные алгоритмы работают медленнее своих линейных аналогов?

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

Не буду приводить пример кода, достаточно вспомнить вычисление n-го члена ряда Фибоначчи: F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2). И что стоит прочитать, чтобы знать ответ на подобные вопросы?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае достаточно простого здравого смысла. Разложите, например, F(n-1) еще раз и увидите проблему (одни и те же значения вычисляются по сто раз). А в линейном варианте вы высчитываете каждое значение только один раз. В общем же, рекурсия - еще один вызов функции (и так несколько раз)) а он не бесплатный и стоит дороже цикла

Comment: @BOPOH я думаю, вы запросто можете преобразовать свой комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @BOPOH я привел первый попавшийся в голову пример. Во всех ли случаях стоит избегать использования рекурсии?

Comment: @Side рекурсия и неизменяемые типы в умелых руках - это сплошное добро. почитайте хорошую книжку по функциональному программированию - даже если вы не будете использовать его на практике, некоторые вещи, которых вы раньше избегали - рекурсия, неизменяемые типы, продолжения, функции высшего порядка -  окажутся для вас неожиданно полезными. вы начнете видеть красивые решения, там где раньше написали бы просто полотно кода :)

Comment: А еще надо помнить, что иногда они (рекурсивные алгоритмы), причем как  всегда неожиданно, вызывают stackoverflow.

Comment: @avp, столкнулся с этим в питоне под виндой, когда увеличивал допустимый предел рекурсии. На #python сказали - если надо увеличивать лимит, значит что-то вы не так делаете. В частности, рекурсию надо менять на итерацию

Comment: @BOPOH, да, это жестокая практика, которую постоянно пытаются опровергать светлыми академическими теориями.

Comment: Я не хотел, чтобы все зациклились на примере по Фибоначчи, просто ничего интереснее в голову не пришло ввиду недостаточных знаний.

Comment: Вот что я из этого понял: рекурсивные алгоритмы облегчают написание кода в том смысле, что он становится короче(красивее). Мне следует прочитать книги по функциональному программированию, чтобы вникнуть в суть. Не все компиляторы могут заменять рекурсию на итерацию. Конкретно меня интересует Java и С++(11,14), но насколько я понял, сами они этого не сделают, к тому же усложняется отладка программы. Не знаю правильно ли я все понял, но легче не применять рекурсивные алгоритмы, а заменять их итеративными(линейными), хоть это и не всегда красиво, но всегда эффективнее рекурсии.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cтоимость вызова функции в языках, которые поддерживают tail call optimization (например, любой язык платформы .net - C#, F#, C++ CLI) практически не отличается от обычного цикла. И даже если эту оптимизацию применить нельзя - вызов невиртуальной функции обычно достаточно дешев.

Поэтому рекурсивные алгоритмы работают с той же скоростью, что и их линейные *аналоги*. Если "аналоги" употребляется в прямом смысле, то рекурсия - это способ организации кода.

Конкретно в случае `Fib` вы обычно реализуете два *различных* алгоритма:

- в линейном вы высчитываете значения членов последовательности один раз.
- в рекурсивном вы скорее всего высчитываете F(какого-то конкретного x) несколько раз.

Это расхождение убирается использованием техники под названием мемоизация ([memoization](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)) - кэшированием результатов вызова F(x). Т.к. Fib - это чистая функция (она зависит только от своих аргументов), то результат ее выполнения легко кэшируется:

вот вариант который будет каждый раз вычислять значение Fib (x) - медленный

```
let rec fibs n = 
  if n < 1 then 1 else
  (fibs (n - 1)) + (fibs (n - 2))
```

[вот вариант](http://www.fssnip.net/8P), который будет вычислять значение Fib (x) всего один раз для каждого x:

```
let rec fibs = memoize (fun n ->
  if n < 1 then 1 else
  (fibs (n - 1)) + (fibs (n - 2)))
```

где `memoize` это:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

/// The function creates a function that calls the argument 'f'
/// only once and stores the result in a mutable dictionary (cache)
/// Repeated calls to the resulting function return cached values.
let memoize f =    
  // Create (mutable) cache that is used for storing results of 
  // for function arguments that were already calculated.
  let cache = new Dictionary<_, _>()
  (fun x ->
      // The returned function first performs a cache lookup
      let succ, v = cache.TryGetValue(x)
      if succ then v else 
        // If value was not found, calculate & cache it
        let v = f(x) 
        cache.Add(x, v)
        v)
```

Кстати, Fib - это настолько типичный пример для мемоизации, что именно он показан в вики хаскеля в разделе [Memoization with recursion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization#Memoization_with_recursion), причем реализация мемоизации там в разы короче, чем на F#:

```
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
```

---

Как напомнил ВОРОН, не любую рекурсию можно оптимизировать через tail call. Например, решение `fibs` на F# выше не подлежит такой оптимизации. Решение и поддержкой такой оптимизации выглядит так:

```
let fib n =
    let rec loop acc1 acc2 = function
        | n when n = 0I -> acc1
        | n -> loop acc2 (acc1 + acc2) (n - 1I)
    loop 0I 1I n
```

По сути, это тот же цикл - функция, которая вызывает сама себя n раз, передавая себе же два последних члена последовательности - но записанный в рекурсивной форме. Примерно так внутри реализован [`Seq.unfold`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs), позволяющий генерировать последовательности, в который следующий элемент зависит от предыдущих.

Comment: Не все языки поддерживают хвостовую рекурсию; например, питон (может быть в новых версиях есть, но верится с трудом) И если память не изменяет, в компилируемых языках хвостовая рекурсия еще на этапе компиляции разворачивается в цикл, потому разницы и нет. Но ведь не каждую рекурсию можно превратить в хвостовую (или ошибаюсь?), а значит от этой оптимизации в данном случае будет мало толку и рекурсию уже можно будет сравнивать с циклом

Comment: @BOPOH не каждые, и поддерживают по разному. например, .net включает эту оптимизацию на этапе jit-компиляции. поэтому там в начале ответа и есть оговорка. да, не каждую рекурсию можно превратить в хвостовую. но все равно - вызов невиртуальной функции - очень дешевая вещь. Кстати, пример из ответа - не подлежит tail call оптимизации.

Comment: @BOPOH вопрос же скорее "что почитать", а не "как быстро посчитать Фибоначи". вот я и пытался завернуть топикастера в функциональщину. потому что правильный ответ - "хорошая книга ФП".

Comment: @BOPOH 1. Да, не все языки умеют что-то делать с хвостовой рекурсией. 2. При написании коду любую рекурсивную функцию можно переписать на использование хвостовой рекурсии. Но не любая рекурсивная функция имеет хвостовую рекурсию и может быть оптимизирована соответствующим образом.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а обход дерева, например, как можно переделать на использование хвостовой рекурсии? Я че-то сходу не могу вариант придумать.

Comment: @BOPOH depth-first обход дерева и в нерекурсивном варианте требует стека (или чего-то подобного). его можно переписать на хвостовую рекурсию, но стек придется таскать параметром.

Answer (score 2):

Вы неверно сравниваете. Вы должны сравнивать итеративный алгоритм с аналогичным рекурсивным:

```
(Fib(1), Fib(0)) = (1, 1)
(Fib(n+1), Fib(n)) = (Fib(n) + Fib(n-1), Fib(n))
```

который приводит к коду

```
(int, int) CalcFibHelper(int fcurr, int fprev, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return (fcurr, fprev);
    return CalcFib(fcurr + fprev, fcurr, n-1);
}

int CalcFib(int n)
{
    (int result, int prev) = CalcFibHelper(1, 1, n);
    return result;
}
```

---

Компилятор, который хорошо умеет работать с хвостовой рекурсией, может преобразовать рекурсивный код в итеративный. Предпочтение и скорость тех или иных реализаций алгоритма зависит от компилятора: F#, например, лучше умеет работать с рекурсивными алгоритмами, а C# — с итеративными.